# teleport-controls doesn't work under Aframe 0.8.2 in VR mode

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr, htc-vive

There is problem by using the `teleport-controls` under `aframe 0.8.2`.
In VR mode with Vive there is only the curve shown after touching the trackpad of Vive controller. But the position of camera is not moved.
In flat mode, the curve is shown and the position of camera is moved.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/21f0cfd9-2fa0-49f3-910b-aedb91df3d3b

```
<a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>

  <a-entity id="left-hand"
    vive-controls="hand: left"
    teleport-controls
  >
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity id="right-hand"
    vive-controls="hand: right"
    teleport-controls
  >
  </a-entity>
```

Maybe has someone idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use it with the camera rig to group hands and head together as suggested in the documentation.

```
<a-entity id="cameraRig">
  <!-- camera -->
  <a-entity id="head" camera wasd-controls look-controls></a-entity>
  <!-- hand controls -->
  <a-entity id="left-hand" teleport-controls="cameraRig: #cameraRig; teleportOrigin: #head;"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="right-hand" teleport-controls="cameraRig: #cameraRig; teleportOrigin: #head;"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Hello @ngokevin,
I use the function, which you have shown. The controller can be moved with the camera. But if I use controller.getAttribute('position') to get the position of controller after moving, I get still the old position of controller.
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/teleport-controls?path=index.html:25:35
You can see it in glitch. After moving is the new box still made at the old position of controller.
Have you the same problem before?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I use the relative position as absolute position before. Thank you very much.